# dynamic excel array based on input

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am looking for a little help in making a formula based dynamic array in excel.

KPI     |    Tgt    |  number | Weight

FCR     |    0%  |   1   |  45%

FCR     |    60%  |  2  | 45%

FCR     |    80%  |  3  | 45%

Leads    |   45%  |  4  | 25%

Leads    |   50%  |  5  | 25%

Leads    |   200% |  6  | 25%

Attrition | 8%  |   7   | 10%

Attrition | 12%   |  8  | 10%

Attrition   | 100%  | 9 | 10%

Abandon   |  1%  | 10  |   20%

Abandon  |   5% |  11   |  20%

Abandon   |  200% | 12   |  20%

So if i have a Leads score in cell E2 as 3%, then i want output in F2 as Number 4 which is <45% hence 4. 
PS: I have a spreadsheet but don't know how to attach it.

Comment: Do you have different cells that look for Attrition, Abandon etc, or does this one cell need to reference that somehow as well?

Comment: I have different cells referencing each KPI like F2 for Attrition G2 for Leads etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in F2:

```
=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/((B:B>=E2)*(A:A="Leads")),1))
```

This will only return matches for rows with "Leads" in column A. This can be made into another reference if you have or want to put that into another cell instead.

[image]

EDIT:

Based on you're comment below, this formula works as well if entered as an array (CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER):

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A:A="Leads")*(B:B>=E2),0))
```

[image]

EDIT 2:

We can cover our bases for an unsorted list in column B by combining the two solution:

```
{=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A:A="Leads")*(B:B=AGGREGATE(15,6,B:B/((B:B>=E2)*(A:A="Leads")),1)),0))}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Jacob. Thank you for this. I have learnt Aggregate because of you. I was using combination of Sumproduct and Index but could not reach the output which you got using Aggregate. Thank you again for you help

Comment: You'e welcome. I have learned it from the grandmaster's themselves: Jeeped and Scott Craner. It seems to be the solution to more and more questions as I learn its full capabilities!

Comment: I guess we can achieve the same result using match instead of aggregate. eg. replace the aggregate syntax with match(1,(range=criteria1)*(range>=criteria2),0). Your opinion pls

Comment: Ah, y ou're right, if it is entered as an array, that would work. Nice!
 {=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A:A="Leads")*(B:B>=E2),0))}

Comment: One caveat though column B must be sorted ascending else incorrect value would be returned. this brings me to second question. is there a way to get same result without sorting?